# org.hibernate.resource.transaction.TransactionCoordinatorBuilder class not found..I am trying to use mongodb

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I am new to hibernate ogm. I tried one small example it giving exception

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
TransactionManager transactionManager=com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();       
        try {
            transactionManager.begin();

            OgmSessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
          Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            Testing testing=new Testing();
            testing.setId(1l);
            testing.setfName("dkd");
            testing.setlName("dash");

            session.save(testing);
            transactionManager.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            try {
                //transactionManager.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}`
```

Here is my log..

> > Aug 24, 2016 2:50:35 PM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager addService
> >     INFO: ARJUNA012163: Starting service
> >     com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port 52455 Aug
> >     24, 2016 2:50:36 PM
> >     com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManagerItem
> >      INFO: ARJUNA012337: TransactionStatusManagerItem host:
> >     127.0.0.1 port: 52455 Aug 24, 2016 2:50:36 PM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager start INFO:
> >     ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 52455 and host
> >     127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService Aug 24, 2016
> >     2:50:36 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate
> >     Core {5.2.2.Final} Aug 24, 2016 2:50:36 PM
> >     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
> >     hibernate.properties not found Aug 24, 2016 2:50:36 PM
> >     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
> >     Bytecode provider name : javassist Exception in thread "main"
> >     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     org/hibernate/resource/transaction/TransactionCoordinatorBuilder  at
> >     org.hibernate.ogm.boot.impl.OgmServiceRegistryInitializer.contribute(OgmServiceRegistryInitializer.java:71)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.applyServiceContributors(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:305)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:273)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.OgmConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(OgmConfiguration.java:33)
> >       at utils.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)     at
> >     hibernatePrac.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:20) Caused by:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.hibernate.resource.transaction.TransactionCoordinatorBuilder  at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-transaction-spi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate OGM dependency -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.ogm/hibernate-ogm-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>

        </dependency>


        <!-- standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JBoss Transactions dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
            <version>4.16.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2.17</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>maven</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.ogm.tutorial.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Use Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />

            <!-- defines which JTA Transaction we plan to use -->
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="test" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="dkd" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="dkd123" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">mongodb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port">27017</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username">dkd</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password">dkd123</property>
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/DefaultDS</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate OGM is not compatible with Hibernate ORM 5.2 yet (a PR is in progress to make it compatible with ORM 5.1 but the last released version is only compatible with ORM 5.0).

You need to use Hibernate ORM 5.0.10.Final for your hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager dependency.

That being said, if it's just a simple example, just let hibernate-ogm get the right dependencies through its transitives dependencies: it will avoid you this sort of issues.

Comment: Now i am getting another exception for the above example.....org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM000044: Cannot load class org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.infinispan.impl.InfinispanDatastoreProvider specified via configuration property 'hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider'

Comment: You need to add the infinispan OGM module to your dependencies if you want to use it. If you don't want to use Infinispan, add the module of your preferred NoSQL datastore.

Comment: i have added mongodbdatastore module still i am getting org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.spi.DatastoreProvider] exception